# Stateless Key Management

Tags: key-management, key-generation

I'm looking into the differences between stateful and stateless key management. I understand that stateful key management means that I have a database that tracks my keys, and can become very large. There are obvious security implementations as well - if that database is compromised, well...that's what we call a "resume-generating event".

With stateless, as I understand it, this is an algorithm that can regenerate keys based on the algorithm that is used to create a static table. This alleviates the "oops" moments...but what if I rotate my keys? Let's say I have a 90-day key rotation policy - would I then have to regenerate my keys, decrypt my data, then re-encrypt all my data? I'm trying to make a determination if stateless is really a way that we should be looking at moving forward.

Comment: You encrypt the data with data encryption key which is encrypted by key encryption key. When you rotate keys, you generate a new key key encryption key and encrypt the data encryption key.

Comment: @defalt this is envelope encryption, which I understand. What I'm trying to determine is whether or not a vendor I am looking at is using envelope encryption with what they call "stateless key management". I've asked and I have gotten the traditional "look over here" while I don't answer the question you've asked. I don't want to make assumptions, but in my experience, that generally means that the vendor doesn't do what I've asked, which in this case would be envelope encryption. Curious if anyone else has looked into this.

Comment: I don't think stateless key management is a thing. Keys can be either stored or derived from another state like passwords.